# make Android Studio Work with Java and not Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

my android studio started working with kotlin and not java after the last update. 
I have a university project that I need to deliver soon and we only learned coding with java, can anyone please help me find a way to return it to java 
thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean it started to work with Kotlin? It has Kotlin files or are you able to create Kotlin files? If it is the latter then you're all good, you just need to create Java classes (Kotlin is 100% inter-operable so you can still do it in Java).

Comment: You can still use Java for your projects. Just pay attention when creating them to not check "Include Kotlin support". Then the generated default files will be in Java.

Comment: when I try to create a simple method like public void onclick (View view), it shows errors , but when I write  ' fun' it works. even when I want to declare something in java code it shows error but when used Kotlin declaration it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, when you create new project you have to uncheck "Include Kotlin support" checkbox at the bottom of "Create new project" window.
And remember that you can create java classes in Kotlin project.

Answer (score 59):

In the new version of Android Studio, instead of choosing "Empty Activity" as usual, choose "Empty Views Activity".
Android Studio removed Java support in "Empty Activity".

Other answers are irrelevant because they explain how to choose Java for the previous versions where it was obvious anyway.

[image]

side personal notes:
This behavior is not typical to Google and is very surprising and aggressive.
It becomes dangerous to upgrade versions these days.
People love Java and are use to it.
It is great that Kotlin support was added but yet Java is powerful amazing programming language that will stay forever.
I use Java also for server side and for desktop applications so it is convenient to use same programming language for multiple platforms.
Android Studio doesn't even explain the change clearly.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Even as of March 2024, only with "Empty views activity" can you select between Kotlin or Java as the language to use.

Answer (score 4):

**Android Studio disable Kotlin**

If you would like disable Kotlin in your project you should delete `MainActivity.kt` and remove next lines

build.gradle(Project)

```
//classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:<kotlin_version>"
```

build.gradle(App)

```
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


dependencies {
    ...
    //implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:<kotlin_version>"
}
```

Comment: This answer works , and as @Aleksandar said I can just uncheck "Include Kotlin support" when creating the project

Comment: You can use this approach after setup a project.

Answer (score -1):

I understand the problem, it's simple, we are just missing the option to change the language while creating a new app. Just change the language to Java from kotlin.

I am sharing the steps for the same (currently using android studio chipmunk)

**Step 1:** Select New project from the menu
[image: New App]

**Step 2:** Select the main Activity Type
[image: Select activity type]

**Step 3:** Find the option to change the language
[image: update lang to JAVA]

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it misses the point of the question of the author.
The author upgraded the Android Studio to a later version than in this answer and in the new version he can't see Java because Android Studio removed it for "Empty Activity". If you choose "No Activity" (the first option, top left), then you can choose between Java and Kotlin.
Hopefully Android Studio will change it back in future version because many people want Java and this change is aggressive.

Comment: This option doesn't exist in recent versions of Android Studio.